# iOS swift clear all array data saved as a object in userdefaults using NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, userdefaults

I saved data i.e all notifications as notification object using NSKeyedArchiver :

```
        let notificationobj = NotificationObj(userid: userid, type: type, image:image, body:body, title:title, category:category, badge:badge)
        notificationarr.append(notificationobj)         
        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: notificationarr)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "notificationarr")
```

And unarchived data as list of array :

```
    self.encodedData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "notificationarr")
    if((self.encodedData != nil)){
        self.notificationLists = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: self.encodedData!) as? [NotificationObj])!
        print("NOTIFICATIONLISTVIEWDIDLOAD : \(self.notificationLists)")
    }else{
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

How to clear data i.e. notifications on clear all/remove all button click?

I tried in below way, but Data gets load again on receiving another notification

```
    self.notificationLists.removeAll()
    //self.notificationarr.removeAll()
    self.encodedData?.removeAll()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    self.encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.notificationLists)
    print("encodedata \(self.encodedData)")
    defaults.set(self.encodedData, forKey: "notificationarr")
    defaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: Just try `defaults.set(Data(), forKey: "notificationarr")`. And remove `synchronize`. Its not needed.

Comment: Not working. Data(Notifications) gets clear, but on App minimise and then I resend notification again, It shows deleted/cleared notifications as well.

Comment: Can anybody help me out with this?